# Snowflake : Is time travel a replacement for backups?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is Time travel a replacement for backups?

For instance, we recreated a schema with tables, we used time travel and the constraints (PK, FK) were gone.

I read something about this : If the precision of a column is decreased below the maximum precision of any column data retained in Time Travel, you will not be able to restore the table without first increasing the precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to physically “restore” a table from a previous point in time, and the table definition has changed between then and now, then your current definition would need to match the historic definition.

Whether you do this as part of your restoration process or you do it as a separate step before you restore the data is up to you

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, but when I applied timetravel on Database level I managed to retrieve the previous version of the table.

Comment: I misunderstand the issue with the precision. Off course is this an issue when you precision is changed. So that seems obvious.

But still the question is : Is Timetravel a replacement for backups? Spoke one Snowflake salesperson and he said that Time travel doesn't work well with ALTER TABLES and advised Cloning.

Comment: It depends why you are taking backups. If you want a backup in case there is a catastrophic failure of the Snowflake account/infrastructure then Timetravel is not a solution (neither is anything that would save the "backup" in the same account). If you want the capability to be able to revert an object to a previous version then Timetravel is an option - but only within the Timetravel window and with the caveats about ALTER. Cloning gives you a (relatively) permanent snapshot of an object at a point in time - but requires you to create the clone at the appropriate times

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, time travel has a limited life time, 1 day by default, and can be up to 90 days for Enterprise version:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#data-retention-period

I personally do not think it is a replacement for backup. A better match is the CLONE of an object:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-storage-considerations.html#label-cloning-tables

For the second question, looks like your table DDL has been changed. To restore the data, you need to restore the table DDL first that matches with the data in time travel.

Comment: I managed to retrieve the previous version (with another structure) with timetravel on database level. https://bifuture.blogspot.com/2022/02/snowflake-is-time-travel-replacement.html